# Swift unique property in multiple instances

Tags: properties, swift, instance

I know that theoretically it's possible to create multiple instances of the same class with a property that would have a different value for each instance.

The thing is, I can't make it happen.

Each time I'm creating a new instance, it gets the property's value of the other instances, and when I'm changing one value for an instance, it changes the other's too.

So my guess is that I'm doing something wrong (obviously), like accessing the class property value instead of the instance property value... Here's the code.

```
class CustomUIImageView: UIImageView {
    var someParameter: Bool = false // This is the property I want to be different in each version of the instance. 
}


class ClassSiege: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {    

    var myView: CustomUIImageView! //the instance declaration. 

    // I use this gesture recognizer to find out the value of the instance I'm tapping on.
    func handleTap (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("value of someParameter \(self.myView.someParameter)")
    }

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let iv: UIView! = recognizer.view
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        iv.center.x += translation.x
        iv.center.y += translation.y
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        var centerBoardX = BlackBoard.center.x // 'Blackboard' is a fixed image on the screen. 
        var centerBoardY = BlackBoard.center.y
        var centerRondX = iv.center.x
        var centerRondY = iv.center.y

        if centerRondY - centerBoardY < 100 { 
            self.myView.someParameter = true // If the distance between myView and the blackboard is under 100 I want the instance's property to become true. 
        } else {
            self.myView.someParameter = false // On the other hand, if the distance is greater than 100, I want it to be false. 
        }
    }

    // When the user pushes a button, it triggers this method that creates a new instance of myView and add it to the screen. 
   @IBAction func showContent(sender: AnyObject) {
       // some code...
       // Here I'm creating the instance of the view and I give it the gesture recognizer parameters. I don't think that relevant to the issue, so I'm not adding the code.
    }
}
```

So clearly that's not the good way to do it, but what's wrong, and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, and if you've been facing the same issu, here's how to deal with it.
The secret is to downcast the recognizer.view to take the parameter of the subclass CustomUIImageView.

here's how :

```
func handleTap (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

println("value of someParameter \(self.myView.someParameter)") //I use this gesture recognizer to find out the value of the instance I'm tapping on. 

}

func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let iv : UIView! = recognizer.view
let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
iv.center.x += translation.x
iv.center.y += translation.y
recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

var centerBoardX = BlackBoard.center.x //blackboard is a fixed image on the screen. 
var centerBoardY = BlackBoard.center.y
var centerRondX = iv.center.x
var centerRondY = iv.center.y

var myParameter = recognizer.view as CustomUIImageView //<- this is the key point. Downcasting let you access the custom subclass parameters of the object that is currently moved

if centerRondY - centerBoardY < 100 { 

  myParameter.someParameter = true //so now I'm really changing the parameter's value inside the object rather than changing a global var like I did before. 



} else {
    myParameter.someParameter = false 

    }

}

//when user pushes a button, it triggers this func that creates a new instance of myView and add it to the screen. 
@IBAction func showContent(sender: AnyObject) {

some code...
 //here I'm creating the instance of the view and I give it the gesture recognizer parameters. I don't think that relevant to the issue, so I'm not adding the code. 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing my answer on your related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25949217/148357).

If what you want to achieve is initializing a property with a value that you provide, just add a new parameter to the initializer. If for instance you are using the initializer with a `CGRect` passed in, then you can implement an initializer like this:

```
class CustomUIImageView : UIImageView {
    let someParameter : Bool

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

     init(frame: CGRect, someParameter: Bool) {
        self.someParameter = someParameter
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

I hope that this is what you are looking for - let me know otherwise.

Comment: Well, not really because I don't want to initialize it with a value when I create the instance but afterward, when the view is moved by the user on the screen. Beside, using your code here just get me back to my initial problem with my previous question, I can't create the Frame because the init is not overriden. But if I do so, compiler complains because someParameter does not inherits from a superclass. lol !

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to do something like `myImage.someParameter = true`?

Comment: Yep, but doing so (like explained above) it changes the value of all the instances. Either that, or I'm not able to correctly retrieve the value from the instance with `println(myView.someParameter)`or `println(self.myView.someParameter`.

Comment: The only way for a property to change in all instances is that you have declared as a class property: `class var myProp: Int`. If you declare as `var myProp: Int`, then each instance has its own copy. However if you have multiple variables of the same type, and you notice that by changing an instance property in one, all the others have the same change, then it means all these variables are pointing to the same instance of the class

Comment: Yes, I think this must be something like that. But that gets me back to and old problem that's not solve... how to be sure that the value of my variable is changed only on the instance I'm moving around in my view ? Using the func handlePan above I manage to get the precise coordonates of the view that is being moved, maybe I should pass the parameters throught that and subclass uiview instead of UIImageView. What do you think ?

Comment: I cannot answer to that because I don't have enough knowledge of the problem and how you're implementing it. I can just say that if the property is an instance property, then it's not about having multiple instances of the class, but having multiple variables pointing to the same instance - in that case your app logic is broken. That happens if you create an instance like `var view = CustomUIView(...)` and then do `var v1 = view`, `var v2 = view`, etc.: `v1` and `v2` are references to `view`, so when you change (the instance pointed by) `view`, you see those changes in `v1` and `v2` as well

Comment: Damn : Classes Are Reference Types

Unlike value types, reference types are not copied when they are assigned to a variable or constant, or when they are passed to a function. Rather than a copy, a reference to the same existing instance is used instead.

It was right in the Swift documentation from the beginning. I have to find another way of doing this. Maybe by using a Struc rather than a Class. Argh.Thank you for helping me !

Comment: You could but probably you can't: structs don't support inheritance, so you cannot create a struct inherited from a class. But you can create a struct with a `UIImageView` inside - be aware though that if you copy a struct instance, and the struct contains a reference to a class, the reference and not the instance will be copied